# VBA click at element in IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I can't click on an element in the screen, it's not a button but works like one. I have successfully located it through the web inspector (I think) but I can't figure out the reason of why isn't working... Previously in my code I used the same code for clicking in a "Log in" button and it worked perfectly. Here it is the code:

```
    Set objCollection = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("div")
    For Each elem In objCollection
        If IsObject(IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group")) Then 'Scratchpad button clicking
            If IsObject(IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pull-left fang-button fang-button-subtle no-margin ng-binding")) Then
                Debug.Print "found it"
                elem.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next elem
```

I'm trying to click in the element "Scratchpad" at the top of the page, [image: as the image shows.] Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" style="border:1px solid #ccc"> <a ng-class="{'active': !CrossSegmentConfig.showScratchPad &amp;&amp; !CrossSegmentConfig.showGraph}" class="pull-left fang-button fang-button-subtle no-margin ng-binding active" ng-click="CrossSegmentConfig.showScratchPad=false; CrossSegmentConfig.showGraph=false;" style=""> <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i> Parameters </a> <a ng-class="{'active': CrossSegmentConfig.showScratchPad}" class="pull-left fang-button fang-button-subtle no-margin ng-binding" ng-click="CrossSegmentConfig.toggleScratchPad()" style=""> <i class="fa fa fa-columns"></i> Scratchpad </a> <a ng-class="{'active': CrossSegmentConfig.showGraph}" class="pull-left fang-button fang-button-subtle no-margin ng-binding" ng-click="CrossSegmentConfig.toggleGraph()"> <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> Plot </a> </div>
```

Comment: Try iterating this collection `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group").getElementsByTagName("a")` and look for InnerText or InnerHTML being equal to `ScratchPad`

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks for your repy! Tried to do so on the objCollection line but this error pops up: "object does not accept this property or method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Angular JS directive. Try either of the following 2

```
ie.document.querySelector("[ng-click*=toggleScratchPad]").click

ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('[ng-click*=toggleScratchPad]').click();"
```